# elasticsearch - find by location based on name

Tags: elasticsearch, join, geolocation

I'm trying to build a query that match a person's address by name and I'm currently facing this situation:

Assuming I'm looking for people in California, my query for california should match locations like:

- California
- Mountain View, California
- Palo Alto, CA

Currently, full-text search solves the first two very nicely, but I'm not able to find people like in the third example.

Anyone knows if there's a way to do this?

---

In MySQL I would do a join with another table with location names and so on, would that be possible in ES?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your address and name information coming from?  I ask because many times the address needs to be standardized/normalized before you can do much with it.  For example "100 North Main Street" doesn't "textually" match "100 N Main St" even though the address is the same.

Comment: Exactly, my address is coming from user inputs.
What I thought was normalizing the field before indexing, but then again, the user who's going to query my ES server doesn't know how I organized the address field.